# Mathematics teaching positions in the UK

Tags: education, career-development

crossposted to https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24065/mathematics-teaching-position-in-the-uk

I hold a PhD in pure mathematics and am looking for mathematics teaching positions in the UK, preferably at University level.

1. What would be some websites where to find such ads?
2. What is the standard approximate salary?
3. What is the standard work load?
4. What is the standard application procedure/requirements? When are the deadlines for applications?
5. Are there any such permanent positions? Details?

Any details would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps good enough for Academia.SE?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have just posted the questions there as well and added the link above.

Comment: You should link the question on Academia to this question or delete this question.